# Python tool to import tables into snowflake

Tags: python, sql, csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to upload csv file into Snowflake, but looks like COPY INTO syntax failed, show me a message of rollback, create the data stage and table is good, I just can connect with ODBC nothing more and also that part works, what is not working is the COPY sentence.

This is my Copy sentence that is the only one that is not working:

```
sql = "COPY INTO \"PAYMENTS\".\"PAYMENTS_USER_RW\".\"STUDENT_MATH_MARK\" FROM @data_stage/ FILES = ('Student_marks.csv') FILE_FORMAT = (type = 'csv' field_delimiter = ',' skip_header = 1);"
execute_query(conn, sql)
```

Here my code:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=MYODBC;UID=MYUSER')

def execute_query(connection, query):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    cursor.close()


try:
    sql = 'use role {}'.format('APP_SNOWFLAKE_BDP_PAYMENT_RO')
    execute_query(conn, sql)

    sql = 'use database {}'.format('PAYMENTS')
    execute_query(conn, sql)

    sql = 'use warehouse {}'.format('BDP_PAYMENT_XSMALL_WH')
    execute_query(conn, sql)

    sql = 'use schema {}'.format('PAYMENTS_USER_RW ')
    execute_query(conn, sql)


    sql = 'drop table if exists "PAYMENTS"."PAYMENTS_USER_RW".student_math_mark'
    execute_query(conn, sql)


    sql = 'drop stage if exists data_stage'
    execute_query(conn, sql)

    sql = 'create stage "PAYMENTS"."PAYMENTS_USER_RW".data_stage file_format = (type = "csv" field_delimiter = "," skip_header = 1)'
    execute_query(conn, sql)

    csv_file = 'C:\\Users\\MYUSER\\Downloads\\Student_marks.csv'
    sql = "PUT file://" + csv_file + " @data_stage auto_compress=FALSE"
    execute_query(conn, sql)

    sql = 'CREATE OR REPLACE table "PAYMENTS"."PAYMENTS_USER_RW".student_math_mark(name varchar, mark double)'
    execute_query(conn, sql)

          

    sql = "COPY INTO \"PAYMENTS\".\"PAYMENTS_USER_RW\".\"STUDENT_MATH_MARK\" FROM @data_stage/ FILES = ('Student_marks.csv') FILE_FORMAT = (type = 'csv' field_delimiter = ',' skip_header = 1);"
    execute_query(conn, sql)
 
    sql = "ALTER WAREHOUSE BDP_PAYMENT_XSMALL_WH SUSPEND"
    execute_query(conn, sql)
    
    sql = 'select * from "PAYMENTS"."PAYMENTS_USER_RW"."STUDENT_MATH_MARK"'
    execute_query(conn, sql)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    for c in cursor:
        print(c)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Any idea why COPY failed?

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load csv file into Snowflake using Python tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67675362/load-csv-file-into-snowflake-using-python-tool)

Comment: Hi,  I just want to fix my code, and looks like this dont open

Comment: It was your question, 2 days ago

Comment: Sorry, that didn't answer my question

Comment: Can you please share the error message in this question? (the previous one got deleted)

Comment: Hi just show me this, 2021-05-27T22:59:00.258 INFO  6037 Simba::Snowflake::Statement::executeInternal: Query ends and results parsed for: rollback

Comment: Also If I run this code directly in Snowflake:     sql = "COPY INTO \"PAYMENTS\".\"PAYMENTS_USER_RW\".\"STUDENT_MATH_MARK\" FROM @data_stage/ FILES = ('Student_marks.csv') FILE_FORMAT = (type = 'csv' field_delimiter = ',' skip_header = 1);"
    execute_query(conn, sql)    show me like the load was skipped file was already uploaded but the table is empty, its like a rollback.

Comment: Can you test again, changing the name of the file before loading it? Can you also try with a different, simpler file? (in case the file is a problem)

Comment: Hi I did, now show me this: File was loaded before., LOAD SKIPPED

Comment: "File was loaded before" happens because Snowflake looks at the file name to avoid re-loading the same data. If you add FORCE = TRUE to the COPY options, does it fix it?